# Why can I not create an account on Ask Ubuntu?

Tags: support, login

I just tried to create a new account on this site Ask Ubuntu using my email and a password - and not connecting Google, Facebook etc. Filling in the display name, email and password on the https://askubuntu.com/users/signup?ssrc=head page, and pressing <kbd>Sign Up</kbd> would normally create an account.

But not here... Ask Ubuntu does not give any error message but nothing happens. Just like it would expect me to click some tickbox to approve my transfer of my personal data, or whatever. And yes, the password has capitals, small letters and numbers - so that's not the issue!

Finally, I had to use my G-account to sign up, which I don't like!!!

Comment: It looks like it might be a problem on your end.  I was just able to submit an account creation using your preferred method without issue.  What browser are you using.  Do you have any browser extensions installed?

Comment: By "nothing happens" do you mean that it drops you to a white page, or just doesn't do anything?

Comment: I tried with Opera and Chrome.

And "nothing happens" means that it remains on the Sign up screen, waiting for me to press the "Sign up" button.

Comment: And now that I tried again with Opera, everything worked like charm (I used a different email, of course). There seems to have been a problem with the service, which is now fixed. I'll now kill this account (connected to my G account) and start using the other one. Thanks!

Comment: Well.... removing my account seems not so easy. Is there a way to remove an account, at all?

I mean... how confusing can you make a a site like this??

Comment: @user806724 On Saturday 17th, the whole Stack Exchange service was under maintenance (updates etc.) for 1 hour.  It was said that every site would be marked as "read-only". That's why you had this problem.